# PostgreSQL NOT operator in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'd like to achieve toggling a boolean flag with just one query.

My query looks as follows:

```
session.query(Foo).update({"status": SOME_NOT_OPERATOR})
```

Does SQLAlchemy supports PostgreSQL NOT (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-logical.html) operator. How this can be achieved different way?

Comment: This question does not make sense. `... update({"status": SOME_NOT_OPERATOR})` is about setting a value not using an operator. If `status` is indeed a `boolean` type and you want to toggle it the: `{"status": True}` or `{"status": False}`.

Comment: Yeah but I just want to update the value to the opposite of what's currently stored in the db without additional query

Comment: @AdrianKlaver True, but you aren't capturing the toggle aspect. The OP wants `status` set to whichever value it isn't already, without having to query the value to decide whether to set it to `True` or `False`.

Comment: I don't have `SQLAlchemy` set up, so can't test. Maybe try `{"status": ~Foo.status}` per [Invert](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=operators#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Adrian Klaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver) points out in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974770/postgresql-not-operator-in-sqlalchemy#comment127181537_71974770), SQLAlchemy's [not_](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=not_#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.not_) operator will toggle the values.  All of these statements are equivalent:

```py
# 1.x style
session.query(Foo).update({'status': ~Foo.status})
session.query(Foo).update({'status': not_(Foo.status)})
# 2.0 style
session.execute(update(Foo).values(status=~Foo.status))
session.execute(update(Foo).values(status=not_(Foo.status)))
```

Will generate this SQL:

```sql
UPDATE foo SET status=NOT foo.status
```